# Callback API ВКонтакте отправляет сообщение несколько раз

Tags: php, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Пишу бота для группы. Надо чтобы отправлял сообщение при выходе юзера из группы. Все работает, но  отправляется несколько раз. Сервер возвращает 'ok', в списке неудавшихся запросов ничего нового не появляется, а сообщения все равно сам отправляет. Кто может помочь?

```
<?php
//tokens
$token = "здесь токен";
$ctoken = "здесь конфирмэйшн токен";

$input = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));

switch($input->type){
case "confirmation":
echo $ctoken;
break;

case 'message_new':
$uid = $input->object->user_id;
$uinfo = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://api.vk.com/method/users.get?user_ids='.$uid.'&v=5.2&&fields=photo_id&lang=ru'));
$user_name = $uinfo->response[0]->first_name;
$messages = [
'/name' => $user_name,
'/lastname' => $uinfo->response[0]->last_name,
'/fullname' => $user_name.' '.$uinfo->response[0]->last_name,
'/id' => $uid,
'/help' => '/name - ваше имя /lastname - ваша фамилия /fullname - ваше полное имя /id - ваш айди'
];
foreach($messages as $com => $ans){
if($input->object->body == $com){
$message = $ans;
}
}
$reqpar = array(
'user_id' => $uid,
'message' => $message,
'attachment' => 'photo'.$uinfo->response[0]->photo_id,
'access_token' => $token
);
$getpar = http_build_query($reqpar);
$sendmsg = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://api.vk.com/method/messages.send?'.$getpar));
exit('ok');
break;

case 'wall_post_new':
$uid = $input->object->from_id;
$uinfo = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://api.vk.com/method/users.get?user_ids='.$uid.'&v=5.2&lang=ru'));
$reqpar = array(
'user_id' => '176628549',
'message' => $uinfo->response[0]->first_name.' '.$uinfo->response[0]->last_name.' (https://vk.com/id'.$uid.') оставил новую запись на стене вашей группы с содержанием: ""'.$input->object->text.'"',
'access_token' => $token
);
$getpar = http_build_query($reqpar);
$sendmsg = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://api.vk.com/method/messages.send?'.$getpar));
exit('ok');
break;

default:
exit('ok');

}
?>
```

Comment: Приведите ваш код

Comment: Добавил в вопрос

Comment: признаться честно, не вижу тут обработчика для group_leave; думаю, вам стоит создать [mcve]

Comment: Посмотрите в группе в вк -> управление сообществом ->работа с  api ->callback api-> правый верхний угол смотрим количество сервером. У вас может быть привязанно к вашему серверу несколько сервером (масло-масленное но как сказать не знаю) и как результат при 1 событии несколько раз приходит запрос.

Answer (score 0):

Возможно следует указать random_id в передаваемых параметрах. Т.к. API может передавать сообщение одно и тоже в течении часа, и рандом ид препятствует этому.

Comment: Поле для ответов предназначено для аргументированных ответов. Начиная предложение с "Возможно" или "Может быть", вы создаёте впечатление, что вы сами сомневаетесь в правильности предложенного решения.

Answer (score 0):

Jonny ответил верно. [Официальная документация](https://vk.com/dev/bots_docs_2)!

Пункт 3.1, второй абзац:

> Use the parameter **random_id** to avoid resending messages to the same
>   recipient. This parameter is active for one hour.

Comment: Обсудить, ответил ли Jonny правильно или нет,  можно в комментариях. Как минимум поясните выдержу из документации, идеально было бы дать пример кода.

Comment: [Вот](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/768524/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b0-%d1%81-callback-api-%d0%94%d1%83%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%89%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5) похожий вопрос. Вы можете там дать более развёрнутый ответ.

Comment: Ну, он кусок документации добавил...

Answer (score 0):

```html
/**
*sql запрос к бд
*результат в переменную $id_bd записать
*
*
*$id_user -  что вышел
**/


if($id_user === $id_bd){
echo("да че все с группы валят надо задуматься")
}
else{
# код отправки сообщения
}
```